# React-native using a state variable while getting data from fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expo

I'm trying to create a simple Expo Snack that converts between two currencies the user picks.

I have two state variables that are updated when someone picks an option from a dropdown list, and I want to use the value of those state variables to get data from a fetch.

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.curr1}
  style={{ height: 25, width: 125 }}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ curr1: itemValue })}>
  <Picker.Item label="US Dollar" value="USD" />
  <Picker.Item label="Euro" value="EUR" />
</Picker>
```

So here I'm setting the value of the state variable to either USD or EUR.

```
convert() {
    fetch('https://open.exchangerate-api.com/v6/latest')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        const currency1 = this.state.curr1;
        const currency2 = this.state.curr2;
        alert(currency1);
        alert(currency2);
        const currRate1 = json.rates.currency1;
        const currRate2 = json.rates.currency2;
        alert(currRate1);
        alert(currRate2);
```

And this is where I'm stuck. The first alerts (Currency1&2) show that the values are USD and EUR.
But when trying to use them to call the rates in the second half I get "undefined" for both.

If I do

```
json.rates.EUR; 
json.rates.USD;
```

it calls the rates correctly. Can't figure out exactly how to format this so I can use the state variables from the pickers to call the rates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting undefined because the values of currency1 and currency2 are strings. To use these values as properties you should add brackets:

```
json.rates.[currency1]
json.rates.[currency2]
```